# Find missing values from a sorted column and insert blank line in these positions

Tags: java, missing-data

Well, hello. What I am trying to do is this: I have a set of key,value pairs coming from a treemap which I write in a txt file. The output is like:

```
1 4 2 8 2
3 8 2 5 1
6 9 1 4 3
etc
```

the keys are in the first column and it is sorted. My goal is to find the position of missing values in the 1st column, insert a blank line for each missing number and write them to the file without the first column. So the list in the file would hopefully be like that:

```
4 2 8 2
         //blank line
8 2 5 1
         //blank line
         //blank line
9 1 4 3
etc
```

I've tried to count the difference between every key line and display a line like that, but nothing. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
...
int i = 0;
for (Integer key : rowMap.keySet()) {
                    String row = key + "";

                    for (Integer[] rows : rowMap.get(key)) {
                        for (Integer col : rows) {
                            row += " " + col;
                       }                          
       ------>      }
             i++;
             if (key.equals(i)){
                        writer.println(row);
                    }
                   else {
                      int dif = key-i;
                        int j;
                        for (j=1; j<=dif; j++){
                            writer.println("");
                        }
                        writer.println(row);
                    }
             }
                writer.close();
...
```

Comment: The code is not complete. What's i?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, tried to keep it clean but missed some parts. Fixed now. I tried to add some kind of counter to count the line number and compare it with the key number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part around the dif is a little bit confusing. But it's less complex as you might think. Before you print a row for a certain key, you just have to print all the blank lines between the last key and the current (if there are some):

```
public static void print(SortedMap<Integer, int[]> map, PrintWriter writer) {
    int last = 1;
    for (int key : map.keySet()) {
        for (int i = last + 1; i < key; i++) {
            writer.println();
        }
        last = key;
        writer.println(Arrays.toString(map.get(key)));
    }
}
```

(For simplicity I just used `Arrays.toString(...)` to format a row. Replace it as desired.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Hmmm, I see... But the blank lines are created at the for loop correct? And how can I combine this with the code above, because I need the lines till the arrow to create the treemap.

Comment: What do you mean? I think the code contains all important aspects and can be modified easily to fit your needs (output format, valu data type, etc.).

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thanks. But how could I print only the values without the key. I used values function of map but it prints "null" at the beginning of every row...

Comment: My code prints the values of the map only. This can easily be seen as there is no print statement for the key. It seem that this is a different Problem. Check how your Map is built up. There are two nested for loops in your code for constructing the row String. This seems strange to me, as the Map value should only be an int array I think.